# Keeping width/hight ratio and using div normally?

Tags: html, css

Im still having a bit trouble understanding my divs. Im trying to make a website that changes its sizes according to browser/screen size.

Ive gotten this far:

my html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="left">Left</div>
  <div id="right">Right</div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

my css:

```
#wrapper{width: 60%;}

#header{width: 100%; padding-top: 11.00%;}
#left{float: left; width: 27.5%; padding-top: 44%;}
#right{float: left;  width: 72.5%; padding-top: 44.00%;}
#footer{clear: both; width: 100%; padding-top: 11.40%;}
```

Now my divs are exactly the right size, the problem is that the conect is always at the bottom of the div but i need it to be like a normal div so i can do anything i want with it.
Whats the easiest way to use it like a normal div?

Thank you for any help! :)

Edit:
Here is what it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/rswML/
... and as i said the problem is that the text is always at the bottom of the div. I understand its because of padding-top but i need it to keep the hight ratio to width andd still use the div normally.

Comment: `the problem is that the conect is always at the bottom`???? where is connect

Comment: Sorry, i ment content.

Comment: can you show some image of what you want to achieve if possible.. much easy to understand of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I added jsfiddle at the end of the post.

Comment: Please write a more descriptive title for your question. "Problems with my divs" doesn't really help me understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that i had to make header divs position: relative and then make another div inside of it that was position: absolute and width/height: 100%.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying here is a responsive design concept. I advice you to try out [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) framework for this. Rather than doing everything by your own, you can get everything done by simply adding a class to your divs.

> Responsive web design (RWD) is a web design approach aimed at crafting
>   sites to provide an optimal viewing experience—easy reading and
>   navigation with a minimum of resizing, panning, and scrolling—across a
>   wide range of devices

Comment: Thanks, but in this case ill rather try to invent my own bicycle :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be with your padding values. Perhaps adjusting them will allow you to have the control you want or maybe a margin-top would be better. Also, not sure if you were hoping to line up the tops of the elements #left and #right but those padding settings may render at different values. The padding-top property with a percentage references the containing block's width. Hope that helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. I cant change margin-top because it keeps the height ratio when i resize the windows. Also I thought the same about elements hight but somehow the same % makes them the same hight, different % makes different hight. Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/rswML/.